# Issue with protobuf values stored in Jedis

Tags: protocol-buffers, jedis

I am using redis to store my key value pairs. I am using Jedis as Java client and values in protobuf format. For storing protobuf in Jedis I am using toByteArray() function with protobuf object. But while reading the value from redis and parsing it using parseFrom() function. I am getting error saying **Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.**

For example: Say my protobuf object in ProtoObject. I using following calls:

jedis.set(("my key").getBytes, protoObject.toByteArray());

protoObject = ProtoObject.parseFrom(jedis.get("my key").getBytes);

But I am getting error with parseFrom as **Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.**

Someone can help here to let me know, what is wrong here?

Comment: Firstly, that doesnt look like protobuf-net (which is a specific implementation of the protobuf specification) - I have re-tagged. However! Can you  perhaps post the hex of the raw buffer? It could be that it is right - in which case the thing to do is: "store and retrieve the data correctly". At a minimum, ensure that the bytes you get back are **exactly** the bytes you stored.

Comment: Very strange thing is happening. I am trying to get a byte [] key which is not present in redis. But when I am retrieving it, I am not getting a null value. How can this be possible?

Comment: I am having following byte[] value in redis. When i did "get Key" on redis-cli, I got "\x12\x1a\n\x0b\b\xdf\x06\x10\xd4\xe2\xbf\x94\x05\x18\x05\n\x0b\b\xc3\x02\x10\x8c\xcc\xbf\x94\x05\x189", but when I get this key from Jedis using new String(jedis.get(Key.getBytes)), I am getting value as ".datOK", which is not the same as I put.

Comment: That is a question for jedis... perhaps the difference between string keys and binary keys?